# Error with logstash Date filter yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z format

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have a ruby (Grape API) application that's logging its dates like the following

`2018-04-07 15:20:30 -0700`

unfortunately, no matter what mutations, date filters, or grok filters that I attempt it seems that the `-` format of the date is causing issues, and resulting in the value remaining a string after logstash output.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), the date format supported for parsing is as follows:

`yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss Z` or `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z`

in order to mutate my date to match that value, i need to mutate/gsub the `-` to a space, but then if I do that my timezone gets messed up.

example:

```
mutate {
  gsub => [
    "ts", "-", " "
  ]
}
# this is not a valid date string
# => "2018 04 07 15:20:30  0700"
```

How can I convert my particular date format to a valid date/time?

```
# this doesnt work
date {
  match => ["ts", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"]
}
```